# Capturing Java "inner" generic parameter in class/interface declaration

Tags: java, types

I am trying to solve the following generic parameter capture problem in Java:

```java
interface MyClass<A> {
     A getA();
}

interface MyClassHandler<M extends MyClass<? as A>> {
    M getM();

    A getAfromM();
}
```

(The declaration of `MyClassHandler` doesn't compile because `? as A` is not valid syntax which is the problem I am trying to solve)

In `MyClassHandler` I would like to use the generic parameter of `MyClass` (`A`) without declaring it as a second generic parameter to `MyClassHandler` by simply capturing it from the user provided `M`.

I don't really see any reason why we would "need" a redundant declaration of the "inner" type parameter but maybe this is simply not possible in Java or I am missing some other trick.

Comment: `MyClassHandler<A, M extends MyClass<A>>` should work.

Comment: "I would like to use the generic parameter of MyClass (A) without declaring it as a second generic parameter" sorry, you can't. It's not redundant: what value does A have if you don't declare it?

Comment: @AndyTurner It is redundant because I am trying to reference the A typeparameter of MyClass<A> already captured by M. M always directly implies a value for the MyClass<A> -> A parameter.

Comment: @Gyula: depending on how you use the type, it might very well be inferrable from the use, but the parameter is still required. If `A` is not defined to be a type parameter then `MyClass<A>` would try to reference a *concrete type* called `A` (which probably doesn't exist and definitely isn't what you're trying to do). By defining it as a type parameter you tell Java to expect it to be ... well, dynamic/variable.

Comment: @JoachimSauer in that case a syntax such as `MyClassHandler<M extends MyClass<? as A>>` would better describe what I am looking for :)

Comment: What about just `MyClassHandler<M extends MyClass<?>>`? You won't be able to use `A` in your class then, but otherwise it would work.